# Devexpress WPF File not found exception on start

Tags: wpf, devexpress, clickonce, devexpress-wpf

It is for last versions of Devexpress (~ >=17.3). Published with click-once application stopping with File not found exception (within Devexpress code).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to usage of new ThemedWindow (new default window class for DevExpress WPF). Due to my investigation it does not work without adding DevExpress.Xpf.Ribbon dll to deployments, which is not added automatically using DevExpress templates.
Adding this dll manually to References fixes the issue.